# Why piecharts begin drawing from different angles in D3?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am creating two nested piecharts using D3. 
Outer chart has 4 numbers array and inner chart has 3 numbers array summing outer chart numbers. So inner chart sectors are like groups for outer chart's sectors. Currently only one group is there now shown - 2 orange sectors and the biggest blue sector for them.

My issue is that for some reason charts are built from different angles. As you can see, inner chart should be rotated about 10 degrees counter-clockwise. I create both charts with the same options, the only difference is radius for inner chart. How can I control this behavior?

[image: Pie charts]

Comment: They shouldn't start from different angles. Can you post the code you're using please?

Answer (score 3):

The two pie charts do line up - at 12 o'clock. I'm guessing that your slices are being sorted by size, so larger, lighter orange slice is appearing first and the second, smaller one is appearing last instead of second.

This is easy to fix by disabling sorting:

```
pie.sort(null)
```

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pie-Layout#wiki-sort

If that doesn't work, you should follow Lar's advice and post a jsfiddle or bl.ocks. Any number of other things could be causing this issue.